# Can't add new language versions to an existing item

Tags: multilingual

I'm trying to add languages versions to an existing sitecore item i've created:

```
//creation of my item

Item item = Utils.CreatePage(cp.CreationFolder.Split('&')[0] + "/" + year, month, cp.PageTemplate);



 public static Item CreatePage(string creationFolder, int val, string pageTemplate)
    {
        using (new SecurityDisabler())
        {
            Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
            Item parentItem = masterDb.Items[creationFolder];
            TemplateItem template = masterDb.GetTemplate(pageTemplate);
            Item itemCreated = parentItem.Add(val.ToString(), template);
            Item item = masterDb.GetItem(itemCreated.ID);
            return item;
        }
    }
```

Then, after the call of this function is done, i call this function to add new versions and fill some fields:

```
Utils.EnableSubItemsSorting(item, "Reverse", cp.SubItemsSortingFolder, lstStrLanguages);

       public static void EnableSubItemsSorting(Item item, string sort, string SubItemsSortingFolder, List<string> lst_lg)
        {
            Database masterDb = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
            foreach (var lg in lst_lg)
            {
                using (new LanguageSwitcher(lg))
                {
                    var sitecoreItem = masterDb.GetItem(item.ID, Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager.GetLanguage(lg));
                    sitecoreItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                    try
                    {
                        var sortItem = Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(SubItemsSortingFolder).Children
                                       .FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name.Equals(sort));
                        sitecoreItem.Fields["__Subitems Sorting"].Value = sortItem.ID.ToString();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        sitecoreItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sitecoreItem.Editing.EndEdit();
                        sitecoreItem = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In sitecore i only see the item created in english and not in french for example, even if i'm absolutely sure that the `lstStrLanguages` contains both values ("fr" and "en").

Can anyone explain me what's wrong in my code ? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the method call into using(new SecurityDisabler)?

Comment: You mean the content of my EnableSubItemsSorting method ?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Or a using statement around Utils.EnableSubItemsSorting() call.

Comment: Great! I promoted the comment into an answer. Would you mind accepting it?

Comment: i just did it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely related to missing permissions that prevent the code from creating item language versions. You could use `SecurityDisabler` just as you did in your first code sample:

```
using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    Utils.EnableSubItemsSorting(item, "Reverse", cp.SubItemsSortingFolder, lstStrLanguages);
}
```

> `SecurityDisabler` causes a segment of code to run in the context of a
>   user with administrative rights, regardless of the context user. The
>   code within the `using` statement block has full control of the entire
>   system, and can take any action on any item or field.